Excel PowerQuery - referencing long query
This is hypothetical information, but hope it's enough to understand my question. Let me know if you'd like to see a sample of what I'm talking about and I can put something together.
In Excel, I have a long SQL query in cells A1:A50. Each line of the query gets its own row (important for me). Is there an elegant way for PowerQuery to pull in this long query without having to do anything ghetto? I was hoping there'd be some way inside PowerQuery to say (in pseudocode) "query = concat cells A1:A50 with a space in between" but just am not skilled enough with PowerQuery to know.
Things I've tried

Adding a space at the end of each line and using =CONCAT() to combine the query into 1 string inside 1 cell. Although this works, it's ugly, not elegant, and easily prone to be broken in the future.

Merging cells A1:A50 so that it's 1 big cell, and using a named range within PowerQuery to refer to this big cell. Although this works and doesn't look too bad, it's annoying having to go within that huge cell to modify the query, if needed. I'd much prefer to have each line of the query have it's own row within Excel.



Try this:

Name your Range of cells something, or create a table from the range.
I gave the column the name of SQL and Named the table Table1

Then code like this:
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"SQL", type text}})
in
    Text.Combine(#"Changed Type"[SQL], " ")


Sorry I'm not too experienced with PowerQuery. Here's what I currently have, could you help match this with the format you commented? let
Source = Sql.Databases("sql_database"),
db1 = Sql.Database("sql_database", "xdb", [Query=Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="QueryNamedRange"]}[Content]{0}[Column1]])
in
db1

I changed the names in this because it's for work and don't want to compromise anything. So ignore the shitty naming lol

@JakeHawkins I only demonstrated how to use Power Query combine your range of cells into a single, space-separated text string, which seemed to be what you asked "pseudocode) "query = concat cells A1:A50 with a space in between". But I cannot debug your actual query. That is a different issue.
